# Add a button into Outlook mail that opens an add-in window

Tags: c#, email, button, outlook, add-in

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In for my company.
I need several things, that I didn't find on the web.
I have a win-form containing WPF to create new entries for the DB and a win-form to view existing entries. After creating a new entry, an invitation-mail will be send automatically. At the moment this mail contains only text.

1. I need a button in the mail (default WPF button) - HTML-button doesn't work for some reason.
2. I need to check, before the button is enabled, if the recipient has my Add-In installed. Otherwise the button should be disabled.
3. This button needs to open my win-form for viewing entries (I want to open it with a parameter: an ID of a specific entry)

To 1. I have currently this:

```
        mailItem.Subject = String.Format("New entry: {0}", vm.ActiveEntry.Title);
        mailItem.HTMLBody = String.Format("<html><body><h3>A new entry is available for you!</h3><p><u>Description:</u><br>{0}</p><p><u>Time:</u><br><b>Start</b> on {1:dd.MM.yyyy} at {1:HH:mm}<br><b>End</b> on {2:dd.MM.yyyy} at {2:HH:mm}</p></body></html>", vm.ActiveEntry.Description, vm.ActiveEntry.Start.DateTime, vm.ActiveEntry.End.DateTime); 
        mailItem.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
```

I guess I have to re-work my HTML-text then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook does not run scripts and does not process HTML forms in mail messages for security reasons.

If you need to enable the button only if your add-in is installed, why wouldn't your add-in create the button to begin with?

Comment: So I could add a button - this would require to check every incomming mail, if it's an "add-in" mail.
This would solve problem 2. But 1. and 3.?

Comment: Since this is your button, your code (C#, C++, Delphi, etc.) can do whatever it pleases, including showing a custom form.

Comment: I don't want to add another button to any ribbon. I want it inside the e-mail body / or append it.
But I guess through your knowledge, you're sure that there's no way to add a button that connects to C# commands or events. Due to there is only RTF, HTML and Plain text...

EDIT:
My boss wants the button directly inside the mail item.

Comment: No, you cannot add a button to the message body.

Comment: Thank you very much, we ended up using a link to an asp.net web app.